# Send "post" data array from different DOM with PHP and DataTables plug-in

Tags: php, datatables

I wonder if my question is dumb, but I really tried a lot of things and didn't manage to solve this.

I have dynamic table with about 200 rows inside a form, and the first columns of each row are checkbox.

This is the form:
[image]

I need to send all this information via "POST" method to another page. It works perfectly, but i start to have to much rows, and decided to use the plugin DataTables, which is fantastic.

The problem is that with this plugin and the pagination, it only keeps the id of rows that we see. If I check another id in another page, it won't save it for the post. The same for the searchbar. I looked a long time on internet, it's because this plugin only save the checkbox of the DOM for a question of optimisation. But I really need to get all the id checked in all the pages.

If I use the "Submit", the variable $_POST['testID[]']  only gets the itens that were displayed on screen when I submitted the form.

This is the other page, where i get all the data of "testID"

[image]

I know it's kind simple, but I'm new to Javascript and Datatables.

The question is, how can I get all the value, even after changing the DOM, with pagination or search bar.

I know there are solutions in ajax and jquery, but i prefer php, and simple post... I am very bad with ajax and jQuery :/ But if you have a solution in ajax, i will try to manage with it. Thanks for your help

Comment: if someone has any idea it will be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, this is the jquery code I used to solve my problem. Hope it will help someone someday :) :

```
<!-- The plugin DataTables only saves the checkboxes of the dom. If we want it to save all the checkbox, despite pagination and search, we have to use jquery to create an array with id of the the test selected. We also need this to create a checkbox "all" -->

                <script>
                $(document).ready(function (){
                         var table = $('#table_id5').DataTable({
                            'columnDefs': [
                               {
                                  'targets': 0,
                                  'checkboxes': {
                                     'selectRow': true
                                  }
                               }
                            ],
                            'select': {
                               'style': 'multi'
                            },
                            'order': [[1, 'asc']]
                         });


                         // Handle form submission event
                         $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
                            var form = this;

                            var rows_selected = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();


                            // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
                            $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
                               // Create a hidden element
                               $(form).append(
                                   $('<input>')
                                      .attr('type', 'hidden')
                                      .attr('name', 'testID[]')
                                      .val(rowId)
                               );
                            });
                         });
                      });

                </script>
```